# Sales Price Maintenance...how to apply grid level user defined filters to select

Tags: acumatica

I've got some code on the Sales Prices (AR202000) that updates values. Right now, it works that it only changes the records in the grid based on the header search. If I, for example, quick search on the grid to limit to "starts with '24'" I still get all the records. I'd like the select in the code to limit to the user defined grid filters as well (I'm probably not calling those the right thing, picture below).

Code to cycle through looks like this:

```cs
    foreach (ARSalesPrice price in Base.Records.Select()) // I assume this needs to apply the grid filter
        {
             //Do Stuff
        }
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible with the filters, I just can't work out the details.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870442/how-to-retrieve-the-filtered-records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer using the link in the comment...

```csharp
        foreach (ARSalesPrice price in Base.Records.View.Select(null, null, PXView.Searches, Base.Records.View.GetExternalSorts(), Base.Records.View.GetExternalDescendings(), Base.Records.View.GetExternalFilters() ?? new PXFilterRow[0], ref min, 0, ref totalRows)) //Base.Records.Select())
        {
              // Do Some stuff
        }
```

Comment: Now that's some nice easy cred :)